# What does it mean to be a "high fee" or "low fee" 401k?

Tags: united-states, 401k, fees

I keep hearing the phrases 'high fee', 'low fee' 401k.

What fee range constitutes high or low fees?

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12557/what-is-an-appropriate-level-of-401k-fees-or-expenses-in-a-typical-plan is a good start, both the question and my answer have further links to good data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every 401(k) has managers to make the stock choices.  They all have different rates.

You want to see that fidelity or Vangard is handling your 401(k).(and I am sure others)

If you have a mega bank managing your funds or an insurance company odds are you are paying way to high management fees.

So find out, the management fees should be available should be less than 1%.  They can get as high as 2%...Ouch

Comment: Employees have relatively little control over 401k fees and while they may feel that it is desirable that the fees be low, they have to accept whatever 401k plan is offered by the employer, or forego participation and lose out on the "opportunity" to save for retirement in a tax-deferred plan.